# Learning knockoutjs - value not adding to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I've recently started to learn knockoutjs ( i think its brilliant. ) However messing around with it and learning how to add to an array i've gotten stuck and need a little help. [Fiddle can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/smzve870/)

Here is my html code:

```
 <h3>We need more animals</h3>

  <form data-bind="submit: addAnimal">
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: animalToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
      <button type="submit">Add animal</button>
  </form>

  <select data-bind="options: animalArray, optionsText: 'name'"></select>

  <p data-bind="text: selectedAnimal"></p>
```

And here is my knockoutjs code:

```
function viewModel(){
var self = this;
self.animalArray = ko.observableArray([
    {
         name: 'elephant'
    },
    {
         name: 'dog'
    },
    {
         name: 'cat'
    }
 ]);

  self.animalToAdd = ko.observable();
  self.addAnimal = function(){
      if(self.animalToAdd() != ''){
          self.animalArray.push(self.animalToAdd());
          self.animalToAdd('');
      }
      alert(self.animalToAdd());
   }
   }
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

For some reason i can't get the new animal to push into the current array of animals - I aren't 100% what im doing wrong, as it puts the value in, but not the text.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First mistake, you are missing definition for `selectedAnimal` but since you are using it in `text` binding, your code is breaking
- Second mistake, `animal` has a structure `{ name: 'elephant' }` but you are pushing like `self.animalArray.push(self.animalToAdd())`, so even if you push, you will not see anything in select.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/smzve870/1/)

#### Pointers

- Knockout added new binding for `value: animalToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'` called `textInput`. This was introduced in *KO 3.2* so if you are using above that version, use it.

Comment: Thank you for the info :) helped me out lots.